# Webpack: Issues with /src and /dist files because of the publicPath

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, dev-to-production

When I run webpack-dev-server, with a publicPath of **/dist**, I'm able to see live-edits for my app (changes to html, styling, js). However, when I compile the app into a production build, the stylesheet and javascript load from /dist/main.css and /dist/main.js instead of from main.css and main.js

The problem seems to be with the publicPath setting. If I remove publicPath, the app compiles with main.css and main.js, but I'm not able to see live edits. However, if I keep **publicPath: /dist** I can see live edits, but now I get **/dist/main.css and /dist/main.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist'
  }, //js output object
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }, //sass to css
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['babel-preset-env']
            }
          }
        ]
      } //babel
    ]
  }, //module object
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].min.css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].min.css'
    }),
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3000,
      proxy: 'http://localhost:8080/dist'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
     /* minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true
      }*/
    }),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
      assetNameRegExp: /\.css$/g,
      cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
      cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
        preset: ['default', {discardComments: {removeAll: true}}]
      },
      canPrint: true
    })
  ] //plugins array
}
```

Comment: publicPath is where webpack has to hit, the url, to get all other chunks. What is you server config? Since you are using live reload, you have to have a server somehow

Comment: My server is just the localhost, I don't have any configuration for it.

Comment: well, even thought being localhost, don't you have an express server or something like that where you server these bundles?

Comment: I'm lost. I've heard of Express, but I'm not using it (or any backend language/framework for this app). Eventually I'm going to upload this to my webhost when it's done. I'm also using **webpack-dev-server**

Comment: oh, ok, now we have a start. So that is your server to serve your content. Ok.

Comment: So what should I do?